# Error when inserting record into mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key, mysql-error-1264

I have created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prices_1d` (
  `symbol` char(50) NOT NULL,
  `open_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `open` decimal(15,8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `high` decimal(15,8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `low` decimal(15,8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `close` decimal(15,8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume` decimal(15,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `close_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `quote_av` decimal(15,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trades` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `tb_base_av` decimal(15,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tb_quote_av` decimal(15,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`symbol`),
  KEY `symbol` (`symbol`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK__symbols` FOREIGN KEY (`symbol`) REFERENCES `symbols` (`symbol`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

which is keyed based on another `symbols` column.

When I want to insert a single record into this `prices_1d` table using the following query:

```
INSERT INTO prices_1d (symbol,
                                open, 
                                high, 
                                low, 
                                close, 
                                volume, 
                                close_time, 
                                quote_av,
                                trades, 
                                tb_base_av, 
                                tb_quote_av, 
                                open_time) 
                    VALUES 
                          ('AAPL', 
                          19695.87000000, 
                          19888.00000000, 
                          18001.12000000, 
                          18764.96000000, 
                          127698.76265200, 
                          '2020-12-01 23:59:59.999000', 
                          2446070334.82879867, 
                          2023802, 
                          63805.39289800, 
                          1223282816.31921670, 
                          '2020-12-01 00:00:00')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE open=19695.87000000, 
                                high=19888.00000000, 
                                low=18001.12000000, 
                                close=18764.96000000, 
                                volume=127698.76265200, 
                                close_time='2020-12-01 23:59:59.999000', 
                                quote_av=2446070334.82879867,
                                trades=2023802, 
                                tb_base_av=63805.39289800, 
                                tb_quote_av=1223282816.31921670, 
                                open_time='2020-12-01 00:00:00'
```

I get the following error:

> SQL Error (1264): Out of range value for column 'quote_av' at row 1

I don't understand while it fails for `'quote_av'` as even changing the structure of the column from `decimal(15,8)` to `decimal(30,10)` doesn't change anything.

I thought it would be a matter of column order but I read on other posts that the order of the values inserted should not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  quote_av is decimal(15,8)

So the following value will be out of range (more than 15 in total digits)

```
2446070334.82879867
```

For this case, you will need the quote_av structure to be

```
decimal(18,8)
```

but if you insert other "longer" values (higher precision), you will need to `further increase` the x and y in decima(x,y)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed I recreated the table with the new decimal format and it worked :)